# How to setup linux relay on vps to allow only .onion connections, with no internet access?

Tags: configuration

How to setup linux relay on vps to allow only .onion connections, with no internet access?

What I want is to block any real-world internet access on relay. So when I use it with Tor Browser and .onion site would have any www.site.com/image.png link, it wouldn't load that image using exit nodes.
Only .onion links.

Comment: Can you clarify? Do you want to use the VPS as a client (to access .onion yourself) or a relay (to serve *other* clients accessing .onion)?

Comment: I want to use it as a client

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** As of Tor 0.2.9.x you can specify `OnionTrafficOnly` flag against a `SocksPort` to only allow .onion traffic through it. So, using this will be more effective. Updating my answer to reflect this change.

Use `iptables` to restrict access to any destination except the `DNSPort` and `SocksPort` and outbound Tor traffic (from the `debian-tor` user in this example.)

However, note that this will distinguish you from other tor users, fetching content from outside of .onion into an .onion is what will happen in the majority of cases. This will mean you'll be distinguishable from the set of most Tor users.

Using something like `ferm`, a tool for creating `iptables` rule sets, you can create a `ferm.conf` like this:

```
domain ip {
    table filter {
        chain INPUT {
            policy DROP;
            mod state state (ESTABLISHED) ACCEPT;
            interface lo ACCEPT;
        }

        chain OUTPUT {
            policy DROP;
            mod state state (ESTABLISHED) ACCEPT;
            outerface lo {
                daddr 127.0.0.1 proto tcp dport 9050 ACCEPT;
                daddr 127.0.0.1 proto udp dport (53 5353) ACCEPT;
            }
            mod owner uid-owner debian-tor {
                proto tcp syn mod state state (NEW) ACCEPT;
            }
            REJECT reject-with icmp-port-unreachable;
        }

        chain FORWARD {
            policy DROP;
        }
    }

    table nat {
        chain PREROUTING {
            policy ACCEPT;
        }

        chain POSTROUTING {
            policy ACCEPT;
        }

        chain OUTPUT {
            policy ACCEPT;
            daddr 127.0.0.1 proto udp dport 53 REDIRECT to-ports 5353;
        }
    }
}
domain ip6 {
    table filter {
        chain INPUT {
            policy DROP;

        }

        chain FORWARD {
            policy DROP;
        }

        chain OUTPUT {
            policy DROP;
            REJECT reject-with icmp6-port-unreachable;
        }
    }
}
```

Setting your `/etc/tor/torrc` like this:

```
SocksPort 9050 OnionTrafficOnly
DNSPort 5353
```

And setting your `/etc/resolv.conf` like this:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: you forgot in `torrc` DNS binding to localhost and host mapping network range. =) just to mention it

Comment: Nope, I didn't but A for Effort, kid. Shame it backfired because you don't know what you're talking about.

Comment: can you be more specific?

Comment: DNSPort binds to 127.0.0.1 if no address is supplied. VirtualAddrNetworkIPv4 is 127.192.0.0/10 by default.

Comment: defaults are a bit dangerous to trust, IMHO - if something can be specified explicitly - then it should be. Characters in configs are not embossed with gold and platinum ;)

Comment: Changing those defaults is unlikely, there is no reason to change them and it would violate several programming principles to do so. This is currently correct and will remain so for the forseeable future.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible in full scale so far by using just Tor. But there's a workaround to do so:

- VM1 consists of Tor, TransPort router and DNS server. Zone *onion* is forwarded to Tor DNS resolver, all other queries are discarded as fails. Hidden services are mapped to local subnet like 10.0.0.0/16 or so. Firewall allows routed-client connections only to that subnet and the router-ip in the isolated host-only network. **No Tor ports are open for this router-ip, i.e. socks or DNS, localhost-only binds**
- VM2 routes through VM1 via host-only network - here is your "onion-only" client without real internet access.